# drupal theming on primary menu, how have all links in one row on scholarly lite

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, themes, drupal-theming

I use:

https://www.drupal.org/project/scholarly_lite

Demo may be found here:

http://demo.drupalizing.com/?theme=scholarly-lite

I have many links, in the primary menu,

```
Home     Special features    Typography   Search form
```

Something like:

```
Home     Special features     Typography Search form
another link      yet another link
```

How would you suggest I edited the css file, so as to have all primary links, in one row?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, it would be hard for future users to see what your problem is if you refer to a link. Please post some relevant code of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the demo theme, main menu link are already in one live. Are you adding links more than the space for the main menu?

Comment: exactly, and for instance, i would like to know, how to make the Special features, be wrapped, instead of being in one line

Comment: In this case we have two solutions. First, we can apply max-width to li. This will wrap the words. Other way we can write small php code to insert <br/> after each word space.

Comment: i would appreciate an exact example with what you would suggest i added in the css file, with the first solution, and then i could also ty and make margins smaller, letters smaller, but then i wonder how it would look in a mobile phone

Comment: Yes for css solution you can apply the li width css only for desktop version. Your theme is mobile responsive so no need to apply this css for mobile.

Comment: so in which line of the css file, i should do which exact modification?

Comment: #main-navigation ul.menu li { max-width: 100px; }

Comment: this did the job, now i need to figure out, how to align those links with one word, and those with more than two...

Comment: #main-navigation ul.menu li {vertical-align: top}

Comment: another issue, i now face, is how to make the darker area, when on mouse over, have the same height. for example, if one word, only the word is darkened, while it would be better that the whole block would be, like in the other areas, where two rows exist

Comment: Can you pls share the link here?

Comment: For now I can figure out only this. But there can be better solution, but will require more css coding.                                                                                 #header-top ul.menu li a {min-height: 80px}

Comment: last question, i need to provide a min width, for the menu, for the dark area, on the vertical menu, that shows in child links, where and how many px would you suggest i inserted;